# Horizontal lines showing only on night shift mode

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, mojave

A bunch of clear horizontal pixel lines are showing on my MacBook pro laptop screen. This just happened today. I noticed these lines disappear when night mode is off. Can someone please let me know if this is just a technical issue with the update or if this may be a precursor for any future problems. please help me ( : .

Also, I haven't updated my laptop to the most recent update because one of my course websites isn't compatible with that version yet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you reset your **NVRAM**. This chip stores information on screen resolution and can often become corrupted. You can reset it by starting your Mac while holding down <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> . You should hear the Mac chime, restart and chime a second time. Then you can release the keys you are holding. More info [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).

Comment: How does resetting the NVRAM help in the situation described in the question?